# How to load external javascript file in svg file

Tags: html, svg

```
        I have create one HTML page like
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>SVG file</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./default.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <main>
                <div class="slider HSlider" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);>
                    <section class="section active" data-index="1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0%;">
                        <article >
                            <div class="slide-head">
                                <h1>Load SVG file</h1>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                        <img src="./01.svg" style="min-width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: -5vh; z-index: 1;">
                    </section>
        </main>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and my second file is 01.svg like

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="11.6917in" height="4.06969in" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering: geometricPrecision; text-rendering: geometricPrecision; image-rendering: optimizeQuality; fill-rule: evenodd; clip-rule: evenodd" viewBox="0 0 11692 4070" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" x="0px" y="0px"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">      
        <defs>
        load css
        </defs>
        </svg>
```

i have load svg file inside html page and it's work correctly but now i need to set some animation effect on svg and i try to load JavaScript in svg and HTML page but it can't work.

i also try to load JavaScript in svg file like

```
        <script type="text/JavaScript" xlink:href="./index.js" />
```

but it can't work.

so anyone know how to load javascript in this situation?

Comment: 01.svg must consist of a single file, it can't load anything since it is being used as an image. Even if it could load a file, images can't run javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

i have just replace  tag to  tag in my html page and load javascript file in my 01.svg file........